# CUDA 5.5 cudaMemcpyToSymbol, __constant__ and out of scope error

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm trying to compile a CUDA example which has;

cuda.cu:

```
__constant__ unsigned VERTICES;
__constant__ unsigned TRIANGLES;
```

and the corresponding code in main.cpp;

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(VERTICES, &verticesNo, sizeof(int));
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(TRIANGLES, &trianglesNo, sizeof(int));
```

How to avoid "VERTICES not declared in this scope" error when compiling the main.cpp?

TIA.

cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CUDA `__constant__` variables have a file scope linkage. That means that the `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` have to be in the same .cu file where the `__constant__` variable is defined.

You can add a wrapper function to the .cu file and call this one from your .cpp file.

sample for cuda.cu:

```
__constant__ unsigned VERTICES;
__constant__ unsigned TRIANGLES;

void wrapper_fn(unsigned *verticesNo, unsigned *trianglesNo)
{
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(VERTICES, verticesNo, sizeof(unsigned));
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(TRIANGLES, trianglesNo, sizeof(unsigned));
}
```

Then only call `wrapper_fn` in your main.cpp.

Comment: In other words, put a function in the `.cu` that does the `cudaMemcpyToSymbol()` calls and call that function from the `.cpp`.

Comment: Yes, I added this to my answer as a sample right when you've posted your comment.

Comment: Worth noting that this isn't necessary with separate compilation

Comment: @talonmies can you please elaborate further about separate compilation? I've tried to modify my Makefile a few times but still having the same error. Thanks.

Comment: I mean, I modified my Makefile several ways, but to no avail, the error is still there. I must have done something wrong. But your comment about separate compilation can help to solve a problem like the above. Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

CUDA is defined by the nvcc compiler which itself is an extension of C99.  It sounds like what you really want to do is separate out CUDA so you have a generic header file.  You could then use it from C or C++.  I prefer to work with data in C++ personally, and as such I have found best way to do this is the following files and include paths:

```
               WRAPPER_HEADER.h          CUDA_HEADER.cuh
                 /          \               /       \
                /            \             /         \
            #include      #include    #include     #include
              /                \         /             \
             /                  \       /               \
            /                    \     /                 \
  CALL.cpp/CALL.c            CUDA_WRAPPER.cu         CUDA_KERNEL.cu
```

CALL.c/CALL.cpp is C/C++ containing whatever you want that will call the wrapper function

CUDA_WRAPPER.cu is the wrapper function which:

- uses cudaMalloc/cudaMemcpy/cudaMemcpyToSymbol/cudaFree to create/free-up device memory and to manage I/O from the original calling function called from C or C++.
- calls the kernel itself in the kernel<<>>(...) format

WRAPPER_HEADER.h contains a C version of:

- declaration for the wrapper function (which must be written solely in C99)
- constants in their generic C form
- input that is different for each thread or for each block
- pointers for where the results of the calculations end up
- number of threads per block
- number of blocks

CUDA_HEADER.cuh contains:

- declaration of `__constant__` memory that the wrapper can write to via cudaMemcpyToSymbol(...)
- declaration for the kernel function with the `__global__` specifier

CUDA_KERNEL.cu contains:

- the implementation of the kernel `__global__` void kernel(...) function
- declaration and implementation of device functions declared with `__device__` specifier
- declaration of `__shared__` memory (it only has lifetime of a block so cannot be called from a wrapper based on what I can tell... feel free to correct this anyone)

There is some of this demonstrated in the CUDA literature and I like it because it really separates out CUDA C as the specialized language it is.  It is only necessary when you are dealing with setting up and running the kernels.