# CUDA constant memory issue: invalid device symbol with cudaGetSymbolAddress

Tags: memory-management, cuda

I am trying to set constant values on my GPU's constant memory before launching a kernel which needs these values.

My code (simplified):

```
__constant__ size_t con_N;

int main() 
{

    size_t N;
    size_t* dev_N = NULL;
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    //[...]

    cudaStatus = cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **)&dev_N, &con_N);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        cout<<"cudaGetSymbolAddress (dev_N) failed: "<<cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus)<<endl;
    }
```

I planned to `cudaMemcpy` my `N` to `dev_N` afterwards.

However, all I get at this point in the code is:

```
cudaGetSymbolAddress (dev_N) failed: invalid device symbol
```

I'm working with CUDA 6.5 so it's not a quoted symbol issue, as it is in most of the Q&A I've been checking so far.

I tried to replace `con_N` with `con_N[1]` (and remove the `&` before `con_N` in `cudaGetSymbolAddress` parameters): same result.

As the prototype of this function is `cudaGetSymbolAddress(void **devPtr , const void* symbol )`, I guessed it wanted to be given my symbol's address. However, I tried with `cudaStatus = cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **)&dev_N, (const void*) con_N);` and I got the same message.

I'm also getting the very same error message when I remove `cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **)&dev_N, &con_N)` and go directly with `cudaMemcpyToSymbol(&con_N, &N, sizeof(size_t))` instead.

I'm afraid I missed something essential. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct usage of `cudaGetSymbolAddress` is

```
cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **)&dev_N, con_N)
```

I'm showing this with the simple example below.

As the documentation explains, the symbol should physically reside on the device. Accordingly, using `&con_N` in the API call appears to be meaningless, since, being `cudaGetSymbolAddress` a host API, accessing the address of something residing on the device directly from host should not be possible. I'm not sure if the prototype appearing in the CUDA Runtime API document should better read as `

```
template<class T>
cudaError_t cudaGetSymbolAddress (void **devPtr, const T symbol)
```

with *device symbol reference* instead of *device symbol address*.

```
#include <stdio.h>

__constant__ int const_symbol;

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

/***************/
/* TEST KERNEL */
/***************/
__global__ void kernel() {

    printf("Address of symbol from device = %p\n", &const_symbol);

}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() 
{
    const int N = 16;
    int *pointer = NULL;

    gpuErrchk(cudaGetSymbolAddress((void**)&pointer, const_symbol));

    kernel<<<1,1>>>();

    printf("Address of symbol from host = %p\n", pointer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, that makes total sense. I must add that I was not able to compile `cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **)&dev_N, con_N)` , but that was only because all the code I'm talking about was in a .cpp file instead of a .cu file. Wrapping my calls solved my compilation problems (thanks to this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535683/cuda-5-5-cudamemcpytosymbol-constant-and-out-of-scope-error )

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, A line of your code should be fixed like below.

```
cudaStatus = cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **)&dev_N, con_N);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for answering!
The prototype of this function is cudaGetSymbolAddress(void * * devPtr , const void* symbol ) so I thought it wanted to be given my symbol's address.
However, I tried this (I had to cast con_N as a const void*), and I'm still stuck with the same error message.

Comment: You should not cast con_N as a const void*. it's cause of error.
furthermore, your don't need to follow the prototype for functions dealing with symbols like cudaGetSymbolAddress, cudaMemcpyToSymbol, because they might be differ according to the cuda environment.

Comment: @Wang_Wang: OK, thanks for that tip.
However, my IDE doesn't compile without this cast... (otherwise I would have been glad to do without it)

Comment: @eyam, first people gave you a answer was me.
By the way, why didn't you nominate me?

Comment: @Wang_Wang, JackO's answer gave more details and explanations, therefore I thought it was more relevant for people looking for answers. I'm grateful for your answer though (be sure I'd have voted for it as well if I had enough reputation to do so)

Comment: I could specify the answer verbosely. But I didn't.
Because of making people get the answer at first look.
furthermore, answering order is the most important factor to nominate, because other people might be inspired from prior answer and give it more verbosely. anyway, That's ok.